# How to get document snapshot where name in data map in collection in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I am trying to get document snapshot by searching by recipe name and recipe name sore in data:

[image: Firebase Firestore image]

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("recipes")
    .where("name", isEqualTo: "test");
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `name` field stored inside an object `data`. So the query should be on `data.name`

```js
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("recipes")
    .where("data.name", isEqualTo: "test");
```

To read about the nested Objects and `.` notation, see the documentation on [fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).